# LWJGL3 shader, triangle not showing up

Tags: java, opengl, shader, lwjgl

I'm new to OpenGL and LWJGL3 and I'm trying to render a triangle. However, it isn't showing up, only the white, empty window. I guess it's a pretty small piece that I somehow forgot or where I just made a mistake. I don't find it after searching for hours now though. Here's the code:

**MainLoop:**

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;

public class MainLoop {

private DisplayManager displayManager;
private Shader shader;

public MainLoop() {
    displayManager = new DisplayManager();
    displayManager.createDisplay();
    shader = new Shader("src/shader.vert", "src/shader.frag");
}

private void start() {

    float positions[] = {
        -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f
    };

    int vao = glGenVertexArrays();
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    int positionVbo = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionVbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(positions), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    while(!displayManager.isCloseRequested()) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);

        render();
        update();

        displayManager.swapBuffers();
    }

    shader.cleanUp();
    displayManager.destroyDisplay();
}

private void update() {
    glfwPollEvents();
}

private void render() {
    shader.bind();

    //rendering stuff
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    shader.unbind();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MainLoop().start();
}
}
```

**Shader:**

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_FALSE;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


public class Shader {
    private int program;

    public Shader(final String vertexShaderFilePath, final String fragmentShaderFilePath) {
        int vertexShader   = createShader(loadShaderSource(vertexShaderFilePath), GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        int fragmentShader = createShader(loadShaderSource(fragmentShaderFilePath), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        program = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(vertexShader, program);
        glAttachShader(fragmentShader, program);
        glLinkProgram(program);
        glValidateProgram(program); //just during development

        glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
        glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    }

    private String loadShaderSource(final String shaderFilePath) {
        String shaderSourceString = "";
        try {
            shaderSourceString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(shaderFilePath)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return shaderSourceString;
    }

    private int createShader(final String shaderSourceString, final int type) {
        int shader = glCreateShader(type);
        glShaderSource(shader, shaderSourceString);
        glCompileShader(shader);
        checkShaderCompileError(shader);

        return shader;
    }

    private void checkShaderCompileError(int shader) {
        if(glGetShaderi(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
            System.err.println("Could not compile shader.");
            System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(program));
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

    public void bind() {
        glUseProgram(program);
    }

    public void unbind() {
        glUseProgram(0);
    }

    public void cleanUp() {
        glDeleteProgram(program);
    }
}
```

**BufferUtils**:

```
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

public class BufferUtils {

    public static FloatBuffer createFloatBuffer(float[] array) {
        FloatBuffer buffer = org.lwjgl.BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(array.length);
        buffer.put(array);
        buffer.flip();
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

**shader.vert:**

```
#version 410 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertex_position;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vertex_position, 1.0);
}
```

**shader.frag:**

```
#version 410 core

out vec4 frag_color;

void main(void)
{
    frag_color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

**EDIT: and here's the DisplayManager:**

```
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext.*;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWvidmode;

public class DisplayManager {

    private static final int WIDTH  = 1280;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 800;

    private long window;
    private Keyboard keyCallback;

    public void createDisplay() {

        // initialize GLFW
        if(glfwInit() != GL_TRUE) {
            System.err.println("GLFW failed to initialize.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        // set window hints
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4); //16 for production

        // create window
        window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "OpenGL", NULL, NULL);
        if(window == NULL) {
            System.err.println("GLFW window failed to create.");
            glfwTerminate();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        ByteBuffer videoMode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        glfwSetWindowPos(window, (GLFWvidmode.width(videoMode) - WIDTH) / 2, (GLFWvidmode.height(videoMode) - HEIGHT) / 2);

        // set callback mechanisms
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, setKeyCallback(new Keyboard()));

        // set context and show window
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        createFromCurrent();
        glfwSwapInterval(1); // v-sync
        glfwShowWindow(window);

        // openGL functions
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH);
    }

    public void destroyDisplay() {
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        glfwTerminate();
    }

    public boolean isCloseRequested() {
        if(glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GL_TRUE) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void swapBuffers() {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    public Keyboard getKeyCallback() {
        return keyCallback;
    }

    public Keyboard setKeyCallback(Keyboard keyCallback) {
        this.keyCallback = keyCallback;
        return keyCallback;
    }
}
```

Does anybody spot what's going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the window is white, I don't think this has anything to do with your shaders. The default clear color in OpenGL is black, so this isn't even getting far enough to successfully clear the window. I don't know LWJGL enough to tell what setup you might be missing. Most examples I have seen have calls like `glfwCreateWindow()` at the start, and I suspect that those might be needed.

Comment: I did call glfwCreateWindow() and I set the color to white with glClearColor in the DisplayManager. I just thought this wouldn't affect the shader, so I didn't post that class source code, but I'll edit it now to add it

Comment: I don't think you check for errors after linking, perhaps you should. After calling glValidateProgram, see if the program is actually valid. More info here: https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glValidateProgram.xml

Comment: `glEnable(GL_DEPTH);` is rather meaningless. You need to get into the habit of checking the GL error state periodically. Even if you just checked it once at the end of each frame, you'd know that you made an incorrect API call and then you'd (hopefully) track it down by adding additional checks until eventually you figured out that `glEnable (GL_DEPTH)` is wrong. _Incidentally, what you want is `GL_DEPTH_TEST`._ As best I can tell, correcting that will not change your situation, but it should allow you to track down errors caused by other things.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the error, the order of parameters for the call `glAttachShader(shader, program);` were mixed up. You first have to pass the program and then the shader id like so: `glAttachShader(program, shader);`. Thank you for your answers though!