# LWJGL3 and Antons OpengGL Tutorials, simple triangle is not displayed

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have started learning OpenGL with LWJGL3 and some tutorials. Finally I have found the Anton's one on github and I started with most basic one:
[Hello Triangle](https://github.com/capnramses/antons_opengl_tutorials_book/blob/master/00_hello_triangle/main.c)

My problem is kinda similar to this one: [Triangle not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271058/lwjgl3-shader-triangle-not-showing-up)

This is my problem. I create window with black background but triangle doesn't appear. I would be grateful for any info about my mistakes. Here's my code:

```
public class HelloWorld 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        long window = NULL;
        int vao, vbo;

        final float[] points = 
        {
             0.0f,  0.5f,   0.0f, 
             0.5f, -0.5f,   0.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f,   0.0f
        };

        final String vertex_shader =
        "#version 410\n" +
        "in vec3 vp;" +
        "void main () {" +
        "   gl_Position = vec4 (vp, 1.0);" +
        "}";

        final String fragment_shader =
        "#version 410\n" +
        "out vec4 frag_colour;" +
        "void main () {" +
        "   frag_colour = vec4 (0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0);" +
        "}";

        int vs, fs, shader_programme;

        if( glfwInit() == GL_FALSE )
        {
            System.err.println("Can't initialize glfw!");
            return;
        }

        window = glfwCreateWindow (640, 480, "Hello Triangle", NULL, NULL);
        if (window == 0) {
            glfwTerminate();
            return;
        }
        glfwMakeContextCurrent (window);


        GL.createCapabilities();


        glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST); 
        glDepthFunc (GL_LESS);

        vbo = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, FloatBuffer.wrap(points),
                      GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        vao = glGenVertexArrays();
        glBindVertexArray (vao);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray (0);
        glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glVertexAttribPointer (0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        vs = glCreateShader (GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource (vs, vertex_shader);
        glCompileShader (vs);

        fs = glCreateShader (GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource (fs, fragment_shader);
        glCompileShader (fs);

        shader_programme = glCreateProgram ();
        glAttachShader (shader_programme, fs);
        glAttachShader (shader_programme, vs);
        glLinkProgram (shader_programme);

        while ( glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GL_FALSE ) {

            glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            glUseProgram (shader_programme);
            glBindVertexArray (vao);

            glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

            glfwPollEvents ();

            glfwSwapBuffers (window);
        }


        glfwTerminate();
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: You assume that the `vp` attribute has location 0 (first argument of `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glVertexAttribPointer`), but that's not enforced anywhere. Try changing the declaration in the vertex shader to `layout(location=0) in vec3 vp;`. Also, make sure that your machine really supports at least OpenGL 4.1, and reduce the version number in the GLSL code otherwise.

Comment: My machine supports OpenGL 4.1. Sadly changing delaration of vertex shader did not change a thing.

Comment: Just to double check, I would call `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`, and make sure that you got a context with the expected version. Also, check for errors with `glGetError()`, check the shader compilation status after compiling them, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution of my problem was using

```
FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(points.length);
buffer.put(points);
buffer.rewind();    
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

instead of

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, FloatBuffer.wrap(points),GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

It works even without suggested change to shader (layout = 0). Thank you for all answers. I obtained solution posting the question on the LWJGL forum.

Comment: I would still use the layout directive as well, unless you only care about running this on your own machine. It will not work without it depending on the platform and GPU vendor.

Answer (score -1):

It is glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); you are drawing a 2d shape and the depth test is removing your shape. Get rid of that and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did what you said but I still can't see triangle.

Comment: Did you change your shader code? In your vertex shader you need layout(location = 0  )in vec3 vp;